# Python Summarizer Sumy

Tags: python, summarization

I am using sumy https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy for python text-summarization

I get this error when I use HtmlParser.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sumy/parsers/html.py", line 6, in 
from readability.readable import Article
ImportError: No module named readable
```

How can I fix this problem?

I have done the following,

```
pip install sumy    
pip install readability-api
```

Comment: you have updated the python in your machine?

Comment: did sudo apt-get upgrade python.. if thats what you are asking

Comment: maybe pip install readablility-api to the old version of python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its really funny.

It is not the readablity-api the author is mentioning in sumy

Its https://github.com/miso-belica/readability.py

The devaloper is using his own project readability

Try using above. browse the above project. Devaloper is  miso-belica in both of project

Comment: It worked. Thanks a ton. What will happen if I also have readability-api installed? Is this a bad code design?

Comment: yes it is a bad code design by developer itself, since the code is conflicting with a popular API. regarding the both module installation read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678402/install-two-python-modules-with-same-name

Comment: That url is no longer valid.

Comment: @pushpen.paul The URL https://github.com/miso-belica/readability.py was my fork of [breadability](https://github.com/bookieio/breadability). Breadability merged the changes from my fork so the fork is no longer needed. Sumy uses breadability as dependency now :)