# Distinguishing between Python modules of the same name / installing with different name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-import, easy-install

Two separate Python wrappers have been made for the Firebase REST API:

https://github.com/mikexstudios/python-firebase

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2

Both have their strengths and drawbacks, so now I want to use *one* for some API actions, and *the other* for other API actions, **in the same program**. The problem is, when installed, they are both known as `firebase`.

Is it possible to `pip` install one or both with a different name? If not, does the `import` statement have the intelligence to distinguish, if used correctly?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678402/install-two-python-modules-with-same-name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing a module, python searches the paths in sys.path by order and stops at first match. So a simple `import firebase` will not work.

There is a brittle solution to choose one or the other, but you will not be able to import both.

Anyway, to choose one or the other, you can simply import an internal name of the packages. If we look at the two packages' exposed names, we get:

```
https://github.com/mikexstudios/python-firebase
 firebase/
  __init__.py
   Firebase
   requests
   urlparse
   os
   json

https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase
 firebase/
  __init__.py
   atexit
   process_pool
   close_process_pool
   urlparse
   json
   FirebaseTokenGenerator
   http_connection
   process_pool
   JSONEncoder
   ...
```

So, you can either choose the first one by importing a name only present in it:

```python
from firebase import requests
```

Or the second, with the same reasoning:

```python
from firebase import atext
```

But frankly, this is horrible IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the pip. All of the packages on PyPI have unique names. Packages often require and depend on each other, and assume the name will not change.

You best bet is to copy all the code from the libraries to you codebase an then import it.